# iPad Settings App Background Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6, settings

Does anyone know what the color of the background is for the iPad Settings app? If so, what are the values to reproduce it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Sip to get the color from the simulator:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85f green:0.86f blue:0.89f alpha:1.00f];
```

**EDIT:**

It looks as though the background color is a gradient and not a flat color. But if you're fine with a solid color that should work for you. If not, you can add a gradient:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.89f green:0.90f blue:0.92f alpha:1.00f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.82f green:0.82f blue:0.85f alpha:1.00f] CGColor], nil];
[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

If you'd like to change to this value in storyboard click the view you'd like to change the background color of. Click on the background color button in the attributes inspector and add the following for the RGB values:

**Red: 208 Green: 210 Blue: 216**

[image]

Comment: Can you do this through Storyboard?

Comment: @David I've updated the answer to include how to change the color in storyboard.

Comment: @David you can put the `CAGradientLayer` code I have listed in your `viewDidLoad` method. I've tested it and that will match the background almost exactly. Don't forget to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of your .m file.

Comment: correct this: `rgb(216, 219, 226)` and its hex is `#D8DBE2`

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(247/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(247/255.0) alpha:1]
```